Angular signal + effect = react hooks?
I switch between Angular and React projects, and I like the concepts of "React Hooks."
With signal() and effect(), I can now implement "React Hooks" in Angular. However, I am not sure if this is the Angular way to use signals/effects.
Any opinions? Any concerns?
Example:
import { effect, signal } from "@angular/core";

export function useTimer(seconds: number) {
  const timer = signal(seconds)
  let timeoutHandler: number | undefined;


  const decrease = () => {
    timeoutHandler = window.setTimeout(() => {
      timer.set(timer() - 1);
      if (timer() > 0) {
        decrease();
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  effect((onCleanup) => {
    decrease();

    onCleanup(() => {
      () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
    })
  });

  return timer;
}

Ussage:
export class SomeComponent {
  timer= useTimer(10)

// EDIT
removed allowSignalWrites: true

Recursive timeout handles with signalwrites in effects. Feels like hell wrapped into a bunch of rusty razor knives. And this is definitely not the intended way to use them, timing operations are deliberately not a par of signals (as of yet). The doc actually says:
"... Because of these risks, Angular by default prevents you from setting signals in effects. It can be enabled if absolutely necessary by setting the allowSignalWrites flag when you create an effect.
Instead, use computed signals to model state that depends on other state."
https://angular.dev/guide/signals#use-cases-for-effects

@Loop
The reason for "allowSignalWrites" is the "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked"-Error.
This error should not be happen if the effect contains only "async" Code und should be save.

@Loop
I fixed the code.
allowSignalWrites: true is not required.

Your univer it's just Angular or React?! Read about JavaScript Signals and come back!
